# If A = (4, 0) and B = (9, 0) and C (0, h) are 3 – points such that AB subtends greatest angle at C. If h > 0 then value of h is

Tags: geometry

***If A = (4, 0) and B = (9, 0) and C (0, h) are 3 – points such that AB subtends greatest
angle at C. If h > 0 then value of h is***

***MY ATTEMPT*** :

Tan C = slope of BC - slope of AC / 1 + (slope of BC x slope of AC)

which will be greater than the angles Tan A and Tan B but I end up with inequalities which  are wrong

pls help me out

Comment: What techniques are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Say $O$ is the origin $(0,0)$.

$OA = 4, OB = 9, OC = h, AB = 5$

Say, $ \angle ACB = \theta, \angle OCA = \theta_1, \angle OCB = \theta_2$

$\tan \theta_1 = \frac{4}{h}, \tan \theta_2 = \frac{9}{h}$

We need to maximize $\angle ACB \, (\theta$). Please note that $\tan \theta$ is an increasing function in the range $0$ to $\pi/2$. As $\angle BAC$ is an obtuse angle, we maximize $\theta$, if we maximize $\tan \theta$.

$f(h) = \tan \theta = \tan (\theta_2 - \theta_1) = \frac{\tan \theta_2 - \tan \theta_1}{1 + \tan \theta_2 \tan \theta_1} = \frac{5h}{h^2 + 36}$

To find extrema, $ \frac {d f(h)} {dh} = \frac{5}{h^2 + 36} - \frac{10h^2}{(h^2 + 36)^2} = 0$

$ \implies h^2 + 36 - 2h^2 = 0 \implies h = 6 \,$ (for $h \gt 0)$

So max value of $\theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}$